# Take away the first word from the string

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

How to remove the first word away in Smarty from a string, that looks like:

`$variable  =  "Word Quick brown fox";`

And make it look like this afterwards on the output:

`$variable  =  "Quick brown fox";`

Is there a way to do this without modifiers? I know you can make custom modifier and then use `$variable|customModifier` and get what you want but I thought maybe there is already inbuilt solution for that?

Comment: There s not a builtin modifier for this. One reason for this is that this type of stuff should be done in the business logic (via PHP, of course). Smarty's purpose to provide a mechanism for creating templates and laying out pages, not doing string manipulation like this.

Comment: Thank you, Tyler, I realize that. I will have to make Modifier then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tyler points out, this should be done in your business logic, like so:

1. [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) on a space to create an array of words
2. Remove the first entry with [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift) (corresponding to the first word in the sentence)
3. Join it back together with [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)

Here is an example:

```
$words = explode( ' ', $variable);
array_shift( $words);
$variable = implode( ' ', $words);
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants the first letter to be capitalized too. Also, you should put a limit of 2 in the `explode` function as `explode` will count consecutive delimiters as one delimiter. So if the string contains multiple consecutive spaces after the first word, all but one space in each group will be lost.

Comment: I will do this. If I use Modifier it means I do it, like Tyler says `in the business logic`?

Comment: @Tyler I thought that the first word should be caps at first, but if you look in the original string, the first two words are capitalized, so I left that alone. Also, for consecutive spaces, a better solution would be to use `preg_split()`, however since that requirement wasn't in the OP, I omitted it for clarity.

Comment: Ah, looked over that. What I am saying, though, is that simply, putting `, 2` just before the closing parenthesis in the `explode` function, it should fix the problem I described.

Comment: Thank you nickb, I used `array_shift` eventually. It works like I expected it! Greetings!

Answer (score 3):

Explode the original string into an array via the space between the words, then slice out the chosen index key. Then implode the array back to a string.

```
<?php
$variable = "Word Quick brown fox";
$str = explode(' ', $variable);
$str = array_slice($str, 1);
$str = implode(' ', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, like I said above I would write modifier for this but I solved it in PHP by `array_shift`.